# best practice in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store historical data for something in mysql (only last 7 days) - should I just make an extra column for each or what is the acceptable way to?

Comment: You have to ask for the best practice in asking questions first.

Comment: An extra column for each what, each day? Each record? I don't understand.

Comment: i am kind of using CSV right now to "store"... then using file modified time more than 24h = rewrite :(, there is no structure unfortunately.. rows would be a username, columns would be an integer that shouldn't be over 2.1b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to store historical data for last 7 days only,
add a date-time column to store the record creation time-stamp,
and setup a cronjob to periodically remove the records which old than 7 days

if you are using file-based data (csv),
make sure categories data into different date,
and each file contains a single date,
use the find command to remove (I assume you are using linux)

```
find -type f -mtime 7 -xargs rm {} \;
```

Comment: I mean, i have rows full of username, columns would be (autoincrementingid, username, day, day-1, day-2, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should create table history with columns (data, date) if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes. Create a history table with the values each day. Have a cron job or scheduled job which updates it. Alternatively, store new values each time they change - depending on your app.